# Waiting after finishing a single queue

Tags: random-variables, queueing-theory, conditional-probability

I'm a little confused by a conditional expectation question:

You have two exponentially distributed random variables, and you need to compute an expectation that looks like
$$
E[T_{1}|T_{2} > T_{1}]
$$

For example, you and a friend are in tandem $M/M/1$ queues, so the sojourn times will be exponential rvs. What the expected time you will have to wait given that you finish first.

I know that for an exponential rv
$$
E[X|X>x] = x + E[X]
$$

because of the memoryless property, but I can't see how to relate it to the above problem.

Comment: well, it is not really, because the inequality is the wrong way round and there is no memoryless property that is required here

Comment: Thanks for cleaning this up! Sorry, I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: checkout my answer below, let me know if it is right. as far as I am aware, this doesn't result in anything that has a closed form, but I am more than happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the conditional joint pdf, and integrate...

Another way: consider two independent Poisson processes with rates 
$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  These could be realized by taking a combined Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$, where each occurrence is assigned (independently of everything else) to process $1$ with probability $\lambda_1/(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$, otherwise to process $2$.
It should then be clear that the conditional distribution of the time of the first occurrence of process $1$, given that this happens before the first occurrence of process $2$ (i.e. that the first occurrence of the combined process is assigned to process $1$), is the same as the distribution of the first occurrence of the combined process.  In particular, the conditional expectation is $1/(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$.

Comment: Thanks: that's what I first thought, but got confused trying to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can work out what $E[T_1|T_1<x]$ is. This should be $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} - \dfrac{xe^{-\lambda x}}{1-e^{-\lambda x}}$

Then you should compute $\int^\infty_0 g(x)f(x)\text{dx}$ where $f$ is the distribution of $T_2$. I have looked at it, it doesnt look like an integral you can easily do.

Comment: Hmmm, I did discuss this with a mate and he suggested just multiplying the probability that you're out of the queue first ($\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}&) by the mean time you will wait ($\frac{1}{\lambda_{1}}). Mathematica says the integral is: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2Fa+-+xe^-ax%2F%281-e^-ax%29&random=false

Comment: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2Fa+-+xe^-%28ax%29%2F%281-e^-%28ax%29%29&random=false

Comment: @TomKealy checkout the answer above, it is better than mine. Although I am surprised that the integration does not work. I should get the integral to work, for the peace mind...